# Double navigation jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, navigation, double, accordion, slide

My main problem is that I want to create an accordion based website in jquery,when the accordion button is clicked it opens the content for it.

But I cant figure out how can i implement,that when is create a top menu for it it also controls the sliding of it.

So for example: on the main content,I click on the work accordion button-- it slides down and shows the attached content for work... but i dont know how to link the top menu's "work" button to slide down that same content.

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="accordionButton"><img src="work.png" width="666" height="84"></div>
    <div class="accordionContent"><img src="7.jpg" width="900"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION (ON CLICK DO THE FOLLOWING)
$('.accordionButton').click(function() {

    //REMOVE THE ON CLASS FROM ALL BUTTONS
    $('.accordionButton').removeClass('on');

    //NO MATTER WHAT WE CLOSE ALL OPEN SLIDES
    $('.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');

    //IF THE NEXT SLIDE WASN'T OPEN THEN OPEN IT
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {

        //ADD THE ON CLASS TO THE BUTTON
        $(this).addClass('on');

        //OPEN THE SLIDE
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
     } 

 });


/*** REMOVE IF MOUSEOVER IS NOT REQUIRED ***/

//ADDS THE .OVER CLASS FROM THE STYLESHEET ON MOUSEOVER 
$('.accordionButton').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('over');

//ON MOUSEOUT REMOVE THE OVER CLASS
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('over');                                        
});


$('.accordionContent').hide();
```

css:

```
#wrapper {
width: 1100px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
.accordionButton {  
    width: 900px;
    float: left;
    _float: none;



border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
cursor: pointer;
}

.accordionContent { 
    width: 1000px;
    float: left;
    padding:20px;
    _float: none; 
    background: #fff;
    }
```

Comment: You might have more luck getting responses if you put together a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the Jquery trigger functionality.Which simulates a given event on selectors you pass to it.

Lets say you have five accordion divs,resultingly you will have 5 menu elements.

Just wire you menu elements to do something like follows:

```
$("#menuitem1").click(function(e){
    $("#accordionLi1").trigger("click");
});
```

Ideal you should just loop thru all the available elements and attach triggers to them.
something like:

```
for(var i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    $("#menuitem"+i).click(function(e){
        $("#accordionLi"+i).trigger("click");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I set up your code above into this jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/SZ9pE/.  You have the accordion working, I'm not sure why you wouldn't wire up another event to your menu element to also slide up and down the accordion.

I would set up all your accordions with a common class, so you can control them all together.  When you click a menu item, you could first close all open accordions with something like this...

```
$('.accordionContent').is(":visible").slideUp();
```

Next, I would move the code to open a given accordion into a common function...

```
function openContent(btn){
    $('.accordionButton').removeClass('on');
    $('.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');

    $(btn).addClass('on');
    $(btn).next('.accordionContent').slideDown('normal');
}
​
```

Then, change the button click event to use the common function...

```
$('.accordionButton').click(function(e) {
    openContent(this);                
 });
```

Then, wire up the click event of the menu element to the same function.

Comment: Thanks Guys! You helped me alot!Its working...although i've got some little problems:
i control the 4 accordion elements separately ,each got a number than i can customize them easily without busting the other... in the beginning of the javascript.js document im closing all the slides, but its visible...so if i refresh the page it shows that the slides are closing.How can i manage that on pageload it show just the fully closed slides?? 
Thanks for helping and for im such a beginner in js,but im trying:)

Comment: Set the style of your accordion divs like this... 

    display: none;

That will hide them initially on page load without ever being visible.